# Express API REST Filter Data MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a Pokemon API REST with express and mongo. Im trying to filter pokemon by his type.

I send from Angular a http GET with the type to filter on params.

Having the following controller.js

```
const pokemons = require('../models/pokemon');
const laboratoryCtrl = {};

laboratoryCtrl.filterPokemon = async (req, res) => {
  const filterType = req.query.type; // filterType = "Fire"
  const pokemon = await pokemons.find({ $or : [{type: /^Fire/}, {type2: /^Fire/}] })
   .sort({ pokedex: + 1 });
      res.json(pokemon);
   }

module.exports = laboratoryCtrl;
```

How can I use the value of "filterType" thats actually Fire in the .find() method?

Is this a good way of filtering data? this is my first API REST and my first express + mongo project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)** constructor to create a regular expression instance with the `filterType` variable:

```
const rgx = new RegExp(`^${req.query.type}`); //or new RegExp('^'+req.query.type)
const pokemon = await pokemons.find({ 
    '$or': [
        { 'type' : rgx }, 
        { 'type2': rgx }
    ] 
}).sort({ pokedex: + 1 });
res.json(pokemon);
```

Comment: hey @chridam can you help me again? how can i do the same but this time with the sort() method and the pokedex property, im getting /pokedex/ always, i just need "pokedex"

Comment: nvm i found the solution, i share so maybe others can use it

`const filterStat = new Object();`
 `filterStat[req.query.type] = + 1;`

Comment: hey its me again! if I dont select a Type to filter, how can I set using Regexp the equivalent * on SQL? `/^*/` `/^''/` `/^%/` not working

Comment: You will have to escape it with a backlash e.g `new RegExp("^\\*")`

Comment: With your info i could search better and found the solution `/.*?/`